# UDP - Multi-server single client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I have a linux computer with a code in C that must communicate in UDP with 4 differents equipments. The computer sends differents commands to each equipment and receives responses, sometimes in parallel ...

I am a perfect beginner, and managed to communicate with one equipment using UDP socket. But now, i'm looking for a way to communicate with all these equipments, what i would like to call "multiple socket", but i don't know where to look/ what word to search to find a way ...

My linux computer is the client and all the equipment servers. I only have one eth port on the computer and will have to use a switch to have access to all the equipment. I would like to create functions like :

```
sendcmd(IPnumber, PORTnumber, cmd , ...)
readbuff(IPnumber, PORTnumber, buff, ...)
```

so i can choose which IP will received cmd ... i don't know if it's possible or if i need to open the socket, then close and redo the operation with another IP ...

So, if I ever managed to make myself understood, where should I look for a solution to my problem?

Thank you !

Comment: There are many ways to handle multiple connections. You can use multiple processes, with one "connection" per process. Or threads instead of processes. Or use four (in your case) sockets to send data to each socket, and then use e.g. `select` or similar polling functions to check for data being received and from which socket.

Comment: if you're sending the exact same data to all the nodes you can look into multicasting.

Comment: With UDP, `sendto`/`recvfrom` is what you are looking for. A single socket would talk to any number of endpoints.

Comment: @user58697 When i use :


`sendto(socket_fd , cmd_final, BUFFLEN , 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, serv_len)`


The only part that define my IP and Port is `serv_addr`, because i previously defined it with :


`serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("INADDR_ANY")`
and :
`inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER, &serv_addr.sin_addr);`


So i need to create multiple `struct sockaddr_in serv_addr` to choose which IP/PORT like the following ? 
`sendto( ... (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr_**i** ...)`


Is that right ? Thxs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single UDP socket for your scenario. You can keep the socket open for the lifetime of your application.

UDP is not connection oriented. UDP sockets are also not classified into client sockets and server sockets. UDP sockets are always bound to a local port, either implicitly (typically for pure clients) or explicitly (which is usually the case for servers). In your case you do not care about the port for your UDP client.

To send to your four UDP server you can use `sendto()`. This lets you specify the destination IP address and port the UDP packet gets sent to.

To receive from your four UDP servers you can use `recvfrom()`. This will tell the IP address and port where the UDP packet came from.

You most likely want to have a receive loop of some kind. If you want to do anything else in your application you most likely want to either make `recvfrom()` non-blocking or you want to have the receive loop in its own thread. But this goes beyond your question.

The most important aspect of UDP is that it is not a protocol (despite its name which is misleading). It is one puzzle piece for a protocol. It is a tool to develop your own protocol. But I assume you already have a specific protocol at hand defined by your peripherals.

Comment: When i use :


`sendto(socket_fd , cmd_final, BUFFLEN , 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, serv_len)`


The only part that define my IP and Port is `serv_addr`, because i previously defined it with :


`serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("INADDR_ANY")`
and :
`inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER, &serv_addr.sin_addr);`


So i need to create multiple `struct sockaddr_in serv_addr` to choose which IP/PORT like the following ? 
`sendto( ... (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr_**i** ...)`


Is that correct ? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Or you can re-use the same serv_addr and every time modify the IP to send to, at your convenience. Essentially you can specify the destination address for every call to sendto() which enables you to send to an arbitrary number of devices through the same socket.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Could you show me an example code of sendto() with destination address specified, i'm not sure i understood correctly. I would say that the method is just changing `SERVER`(=IP) and redoing `inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER, &serv_addr.sin_addr`so sendto() has taken into account the new server IP but i'm really not sure about this... Thank you for your help, really helpful !

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your the `sentto()` call will send the packet to whatever  your `&serv_addr.sin_addr` points to, which contains an IP address and a port. This is the destination address the packet will go to. You can send every packet to a different IP and/or port if you want. There is no such thing as a UDP connection. There is no persistent state from the last call to sendto() to the next.